# Deep Learning Predictions Seem Off

Tags: r, random-forest, deep-learning

I'm doing a linear regression using the h2o deep learning interface with R.  I'm comparing the predictions to the ones I'm getting from the randomForest R module.  The predictions from randomForest seem to roughly match up with what I'd expect given the distribution of the variable that I'm trying to predict.  However, the predictions from the h2o deep learning module don't seem to match up with what I'd expect.  Here's the summary from the variable I'm trying to predict:

```
Profit            
Min.   :-1438.56  
1st Qu.: -133.80  
Median :   -0.59  
Mean   :   19.54  
3rd Qu.:  127.39  
Max.   :  508.41
```

and here are the predictions from h2o deep learning:

```
preddp             
Min.   :-0.079954  
1st Qu.:-0.017919  
Median :-0.010088  
Mean   :-0.011903  
3rd Qu.:-0.003921  
Max.   : 0.060259
```

and here are the predictions from randomForest:

```
Min.       1st Qu.  Median   Mean     3rd Qu. Max. 
-212.500   -6.346   20.530   24.690   50.600  244.700
```

which is roughly what I'd expect.  Why are the h2o deep learning predictions so strange?  Also the correction between the predictions and the target variable are strongly positive with randomForest and even more strongly negative with h2o deep learning so I figure I have to be doing something wrong.

Here's the command I'm using to train the deep learning model:

```
sdmodel.deep <- h2o.deeplearning(columnIndices, 7, df, classification=FALSE)
```

Comment: Dave - can you send me the dataset and the logs from your H2O run? I'd like to reproduce your problem. I would think that the model is either not converged at all, or otherwise hindered. It should be easily possible to get very competitive results, if not better results than with a RF model. Please send your files to support@h2o.ai. Thanks! PS. You're doing NON-linear regression :)

Comment: its the same for my deep neural network .....in last layer i am using linear regression ... but the range of DNN output is very very small....althought the network is able to follow the shape of target data but it shrinks the range .....